# I have created firefox search bar extension. How to add it automatically in firefox?

Tags: xml, firefox, firefox-addon

I have created a search bar extension for my search engine. htto://www.oyee.org. The extension is in XML. but when i try to open it in firefox ,firefox displays its code only instead of installing. I have to place it manually in the searchplugins folder to make it work. How can i make this thing install automatically so when any one clicks on my link the xml file ask for "Add to search bar" like other search engines.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the user whether he wants to install your search engine using this code:

```
window.external.AddSearchProvider("http://www.oyee.org/oyee.xml");
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/adding_search_engines_from_web_pages for more details. Note that Firefox normally recognizes search engines automatically (clicking search engine selector displays "Add Foo Bar" entry) but your `<link rel="search">` tag uses wrong quotation marks (character code 8221 instead of 22).